# Java on Heroku/Jetty

Tags: java, jdbc, heroku

I am developing a DB based application on **Heroku + Jetty** stack. I am using **Heroku Postgres** as database. I have a DB utility class that connects to database and returns connection. However, I keep getting following errors:

If I run the following code, I get **"No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-243-131-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com/d4s7l8b2vf1o8c"** error.

```
            URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));
            String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
            String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
            String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + dbUri.getPath();
            System.err.println("***** dbUrl IS CREATED ******");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);
            System.err.println("***** CONNECTION IS CREATED ******");
```

I came across some comments suggesting adding following code to load the driver

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

If I do this, I get a **Null Pointer Exception** after the line.

Please help in identifying the error if someone have had similar challenge earlier. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vineet

Comment: post the error trace you are getting, also the nullpointer trace

Comment: ←[36m2012-12-08T06:26:11+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
←[36m2012-12-08T06:26:11+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-243-131-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com/d4s7l8b2vf1o8c
←[36m2012-12-08T06:26:11+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)

Comment: post the null pointer trace after you try Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

Comment: Thanks for following up but I just resolved the issue. Had dependency missing from pom file.

<dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version>
 </dependency>

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) in the answer box below so this doesn't look like an unanswered question? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for following up but I just resolved the issue.

Had dependency missing from pom file.

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>postgresql</groupId> 
<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId> 
<version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version> 
</dependency>
```

Thanks.